# What is the probability that two people will be in the same group when twelve people are divided into 3 groups of 4?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A group of 12 people are going out to a concert on Saturday night. The group will take three cars with four people in each car. If they distribute themselves at random, what is the probability that A and B will be in the same car?

I tried (12C2*10C2*8C4*4C4)/(12C4*8C4*4C4) because you're choosing two first and then sorting the rest. This gave me a more than 100% probability.

The answer at the back is 0.273 assuming the cars are non-distinct.
The closest I came to it was 4C2/12C3 but I'm not sure why this works.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

How many pairs are there? And of how many of these pairs can be said that they are in the same car after the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The first person goes into one of the groups. What is the probability that the second person also goes into that group? (There are three empty spots left in that group).